# nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, callable

I am new to multi-threading in Java and trying to make a Spring project with Callable interface and Future Class.

I am fetching all the records in dynamo db and for each record I am makin a multi-threaded call to an external service.

But I am getting this error:

> nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null] with root cause

***My Code :***

Controller:

```
@Autowired
public RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
public MyCallable myCallable;
@GetMapping("/myApp-multithread")
public String getQuoteOnSepThread() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("#################################################Multi Threaded Post Call######################");
    ExecutorService executor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Future<String>> myFutureList= new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    Iterable<Customer> customerIterable=repo.findAll();
    List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    customerIterable.forEach(customers::add);


    for(Customer c:customers) {

        myCallable.sendCustomerToInterface(c);
        //System.out.println(c);
        Future<String> future= executor.submit(myCallable);
        myFutureList.add(future);

    }

    for(Future<String> fut:myFutureList) {
        fut.get();
    }
    executor.shutdown();

    long timeElapsed= (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)-startTime;

    System.out.println("->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Time Elapsed In Multi Threaded Post Call<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-"+timeElapsed);
    return "Success";

}
```

MyCallable Class:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String>{

@Autowired
public RestTemplate restTemplate;

//int index=-1;

Customer c= c= new Customer();;
public void sendCustomerToInterface(Customer cust) {

    c= cust;
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Customer no"+ c.getId() +"On thread Number"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:3000/save", c, String.class);

}

}
```

Can someone help me with this

***Edit:***

Full Stack Trace with of the error:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
>       at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:707) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:387) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at com.OCADemoClient.OCADemoClient.MyCallable.call(MyCallable.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.OCADemoClient.OCADemoClient.MyCallable.call(MyCallable.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

Comment: can you share the full stacktrace when doing a POST call

Comment: I have added the full stack trace of the error

Comment: It simply show that org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 means there is problem with communication. can you please try your restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:3000/save", c, String.class); with any rest client and check its working or not.

Comment: @Pant Stil same error after making the suggested changes. But this time , stack trace was printed for each  element which faced the error. and still only the last element is being printed again and again

Comment: @ArunKumar I tried that Arun and it is working fine with Potman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html):

> Exception thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception.

The problem seems to be that for some `Customer` the call

```
    restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:3000/save", c, String.class);
```

results in a server error with an HTTP response code "500"

---

I only noticed after reading your comment:

You have only **one** `MyCallable` that is shared over all `Customer`s.

This won't work, because your `MyCallable` is a stateful object (it stores the `Customer` with `void sendCustomerToInterface(Customer cust)` and needs to retrieve this specific `Customer` later in the `call()` method).

To make it work you could rewrite `MyCallable` like this:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String>{

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private Customer c;

    public MyCallable(RestTemplate rt, Customer cust) {
        this.restTemplate = rt;
        this.c = cust;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Customer no"+ c.getId() +"On thread Number"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:3000/save", c, String.class);

    }
}
```

and in the controller you would write

```
for(Customer c:customers) {

    MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable(restTemplate, c);
    //System.out.println(c);
    Future<String> future= executor.submit(myCallable);
    myFutureList.add(future);

}
```

---

BTW your code is inefficient. You could skip generating the `customers` list and just write

```
for (Customer c: repo.findAll()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is: In MyCallable class  System.out.println("Customer no"+ c.getId() +"On thread Number"+Thread.currentThread().getId());. This line is printing only the last customer which was sent to it again and again. I am not sure why is this happening.

Comment: @KshitizSharma I've updated my response after reading your comment

Comment: and I will then autowire the RestTemplate in the controller instead of MyCallable, right?

Comment: Hey Thanks Thomas.. This solution works. :) Can you please elaborate a little what was the issue and How it got resolved? Actually, I am new to Java

Comment: Basically, you are creating a new Callable objects instance instead of letting spring to create singleton instance

Comment: And also instead of fetching all the records at once. How can I achieve fetching fixed no of records, say 50, and then make the multithreaded call, and go back and do it for another 50, till each one is done?

Comment: I am using JPA.

Comment: Ask it as a separate question